# How to create a number row/column based on 2 user inputs?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say I have two inputs:

```
input1 = int(input("enter number")) #Lets give the example 5 right now
input2 = int(input("enter 2nd number"))#Lets give the example 6 right now
```

I want to print the outcome:

```
1 1 1 1 1    #5 columns, and 6 rows
2 2 2 2 2
3 3 3 3 3
4 4 4 4 4
5 5 5 5 5
6 6 6 6 6
```

I was thinking of using a nested for loop:

```
for i in range(input1):
   for j in range(input2):
       #rest of code
```

But im not sure how to write the rest. Any help would be much appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- You can use string multiplication in Python: `"-" * 3` becomes `---`.
- You can also write to the console without a newline character: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print
- You can use f-strings: `print(f"{i}, {j}")`.

Example:

```
for row in range(5):
    for col in range(6):
        print(f"{row}", end=" ")
    print("")  # A newline
```

Result:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 1 1 1
2 2 2 2 2 2
3 3 3 3 3 3
4 4 4 4 4 4
```

--> You still have to adjust it, so that all the details are correct. For example, Python is 0-index. But you can fix this easily.

Comment: Thank you! Do you mind explaining me the line: print(f"{row}", end=" ") ?

Comment: Absolutely: [Reference](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/). So, `f"{row}"` becomes a string with 1, 2, 3 etc as content depending on what the value of "row" is (see line 1). Now, the `end` option. That is explained in the linked documentation to `print`. It ends every print function with a space, instead of with the normal `\n`.

Comment: @Eren145 You should go with the string multiplication which uses only 1 `for-loop` instead of using 2 `for-loop`s.

Comment: @Eren145 `for i in col: print(f'{i} '*row)` is enough.

Comment: @Ch3steR oh how come?

Comment: @Eren145 a nested for loop would take O(n^2)

Comment: Ch3steR's idea may be more efficient if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: @ScarletCoder16 Oh i see. Im not too familiar with complexity right now, but I think I see what you are saying! Thanks!

Comment: @Eren145 If you would like you can read up on complexity: https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/analyzing-complexity-code-python Hope that helps! Happy coding!

Comment: @ScarletCoder16 String multiplication also takes `O(N^2)`.

Comment: @ScarletCoder16 To build a string of size `n` use need `n` operations.

Comment: @Ch3steR oh ok. Thanks for clarifying that!

Answer (score 2):

You can get this by single for loop

```
for i in range(1,input2+1): 
   print(" ".join([str(i)]*input1))
```

Comment: You can simply write it like this. `for i in range(1,input2+1): print(f'{i} '*input1)`